# Display Excel sheet with macro inside form

Tags: vba, excel

I got application in .net and I would like to display excel sheet with macro inside my form. I found code that display excel file inside panel and everything works ok but once I run macro its frozen. If I will not run macro Its work fine.

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.office.interop.excel
Imports office = Microsoft.office.core



Public Class Form1
   Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
    Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
    Private Sub btnShowExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowExcel.Click
        Dim sExcelFileName = "D:\123.xlsm"
        Dim oExcel As New Excel.Application
        oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
        oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sExcelFileName)
        oExcel.Application.WindowState = excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal
        oExcel.Visible = True
        SetParent(oExcel.Hwnd, pnlExcel.Handle)
        SendMessage(oExcel.Hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
    End Sub


End Class
```

Could anyone help me to change this code or find different one so I could display excel file with macro and macro will work without any problem.

Thanks 
Regards
Mark

Comment: What I want to do is application with something like menu to many different excel sheet. So user can find and have access to all excel files in one place.